# "Send Email Message" on Save Action not sending Email

Tags: wffm, sitecore-forms

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 Update 1 and i'm trying to implement WFFM in my instance. I followed all steps as mentioned and gave all the parameters in Content Editor. Still it is not sending Mails. The data is getting stored in DB only the sending Mail is not happening.

Any suggestion what may be the issue?

[image]

These are the parameters which i have given and

[image]

this is the email which im trying to send.
Is there anything else which is required to give?

Comment: If data is stored in DB in Forms tables, can you update your question with sending mail code? Also how sending emails is configured? Can you add breakpoint in your sending email function and check whether it is even hit? Or increase log level if you are using something OOTB...

Comment: @PeterProcházka I have updated the question.

Comment: I have a wffm form and on submitting that form i want to send a email with details given. Can you suggest me a best way to do it...

Comment: In the Submit parameters you are using smtp.domain.com as Host URL. This is only fake for the screenshot or you have it configured like it? If you have it configured like that, you need to use proper SMTP server URL. Also make sure that the sitecore servers can reach SMTP server and firewall or any another network device is not blocking this...